# Problema con Tkinter y Pickle (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

buenas noches, molesto por una consulta.

Estoy haciendo un programa gráfico en `Python` con `Tkinter` y estoy utilizando la persistencia de datos con archivos, al momento de crear un objeto nuevo del tipo Cliente, este cliente cuenta con una numeración, dicha numeración se va generando automaticamente con una función que cuenta la cantidad de registros que existen en dicho archivo. Al momento de modificar un Cliente, la modificación es exitosa pero el problema me surgue al querer crear un nuevo cliente con el archivo ya existente que venia trabajando y con una modificación de otro Cliente ya realizada; como dije anteriormente, la numeración se va generando automaticamente con la función y al momento de hacer la carga o load de un registro, me salta una excepción de `Tkinter`.

El bloque que controla la numeración del Cliente, es el siguiente:

```py
def get_number_id(archive):

    value = 0
    archive.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

    if os.path.getsize('system.s32'):
        tam = os.path.getsize('system.s32')
        while archive.tell() < tam:
            pickle.load(archive)
            value += 1

    return value
```

La excepción que me genera `Tkinter`, es la siguiente:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/User/Desktop/Sistema S32/S32/s32.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    but_exit
  File "D:\User\Desktop\Sistema S32\S32\abm.py", line 98, in add_user
    str_id_cliente.set(f'{get_number_id(archivo) + 1}')
  File "D:\User\Desktop\Sistema S32\S32\abm.py", line 42, in get_number_id
    pickle.load(archivo)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

¿A que se puede deber?

Muchas gracias y disculpen las molestias!

***PRIMERA EDICIÓN***

Otro tipo de excepción que me lanza `tkinter` es:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/User/Desktop/Sistema S32/S32/s32.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    but_exit
  File "D:\User\Desktop\Sistema S32\S32\abm.py", line 98, in add_user
    str_id_cliente.set(f'{get_number_id(archivo) + 1}')
  File "D:\User\Desktop\Sistema S32\S32\abm.py", line 42, in get_number_id
    pickle.load(archive)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x01'.
```

***SEGUNDA EDICIÓN***

Otro tipo de excepción que me lanza `tkinter` es:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/User/Desktop/Sistema S32/S32/s32.py", line 45, in <lambda>
    but_exit
  File "D:\User\Desktop\Sistema S32\S32\abm.py", line 98, in add_user
    str_id_cliente.set(f'{get_number_id(archivo) + 1}')
  File "D:\User\Desktop\Sistema S32\S32\abm.py", line 42, in get_number_id
    pickle.load(archive)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'n'.
```

***TERCERA EDICIÓN***

Agrego la función para guardar datos en archivo.

```py
def save_file(archivo, ent_info, str_info, numero, nom_ape, telefono, direccion, localidad):
    persona = registros.Persona(numero.get(), nom_ape.get(), telefono.get(), direccion.get(), localidad.get())
    pickle.dump(persona, archivo)

    ent_info.config(fg='#32b222')
    str_info.set(f'{nom_ape.get()} se registro en el sistema')

    numero.set(str(int(numero.get()) + 1))
    nom_ape.set('')
    telefono.set('')
    direccion.set('')
    localidad.set('')
```

Comment: ¿Qué es system.s32?

Comment: @FJSevilla, system.s32 es un archivo binario el cual yo creo mediante la función open() de `Python`.
P.D.: Se agradece un saludo.

Comment: ¿Pero es el mismo que el que pasas mediante el argumento archive?

Comment: @FJSevilla, exacto, es el mismo que paso como argumento en otra parte del código

Comment: Deberias agregar también como serializas, cómo generas el archivo de pickle, no solo como lo lees. Obtener iterativamente objetos mediante múltiples llamadas a load no es tan trivial como parece, Pickle funciona de forma recursiva internamente. Generalmente es mejor usar una sola llamada a dump y una sola llamada a load y usar un solo objeto que actúe de contenedor, por ejemplo una lista o un diccionario. Intenta agregar un [mcve].

Comment: @FJSevilla, ya lo agrego

Comment: Ok, ¿esa función la llamas una sola vez o la llamas de forma repetida, es decir serializando múltiples objetos `registros.Persona` en el mismo archivo?

Comment: Generalmente es mejor usar una sola llamada a dump y una sola llamada a load y usar un solo objeto que actúe de contenedor, por ejemplo una lista o un diccionario.

@FJSevilla, esa es buena idea, en la universidad siempre aplique la forma de generar y guardar el archivo mediante el uso iterativo del dump y la misma forma de cargar, pero aplicado a programas chicos, sin interfaz gráfica... Generar un vector, trabajar sobre ese vector y una vez listo, cargarlo al archivo, no parece mala idea.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96714/discussion-between-flacpu-and-fjsevilla).